# Regular expression: find repetitive matches followed by specific word

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string like that

> FTE YUY:  TTE H478-  IIE HL-315, qerbgadfvsadfs  TTE E581  IIE 362,  gfkgjkgf  TTE A635  IIE 150717, RRNLIP RING  TTE 478-3   IIE  RRN751, sgnyjen    FTE GWU:  TTE 3820K  IIE HL1078, adsvdfbdsb  TTE 581   IIE 101,  asgfasgf  TTE A35-1  IIE 66765,  RRNLIP reqgwr  TTE 47816-3  IIE RRN607,   zvbsdbgf

and need to find repetitive matches of the codes after TTE and IIE, like `(?:TTE) *(.+?) *(?:IIE) *(.+?) *(?:,)` does, but i need to find the word immediately after FTE, too. So my matches would be:

YUY H478- HL-315

YUY E581 362

YUY A635 150717

YUY 478-3 RRN751

GWU 3820K HL1078

GWU 581 101

GWU A35-1 66765

GWU 47816-3 RRN607

Also expressions should only match if the codes are following FTE (YUY|GWU), i.e. `(?:FTE )(YUY|GWU)`

https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this output?

```
YUY H478- HL-315
    E581 362
    A635 150717
    478-3 RRN751
GWU 3820K HL1078
    581 101
    A35-1 66765
    47816-3 RRN607
```

You may try this regex

```
.*?(YUY|GWU|(?=TTE)).*?(?:TTE)\s*([-\w]+)\s*(?:IIE)\s*([-\w]+)(?:(?!TTE|IIE|YUY|GWU).)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/10)

As you can see, "`YUY` or `GWU`" is captured to `group 1` and `TTE` value captured to `group 2` and `IIE` value to `group 3`.

But, it seems "`YUY` or `GWU`" value is appeared and captured only when the value was changed, otherwise nothing(`""`) is captured to `group 1`. So I think you can compensate the insufficiency of this regex by referencing the value extracted from the previous `group 1` in your python script.

Comment: It looks good for that problem. But i copied the string and appended it at the end and it doesn't find the second YUY https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/9

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo error that I mis-typed YUY with YUV in the previous regex. Now I fixed that typo error and works well for your case. Please try again. thank you:-)